# python programming string handling

Tags: python

For an expression with parentheses, we can define the nesting depth as the maximum number of parentheses that are open when reading the expression from left to right. For instance, the nesting depth of "(33+77)(44-12)" is 1, while the nesting depth of "(a(b+c)-d)(e+f)" is 2.

Write a Python function depth(s) that takes a string containing an expression with parentheses and returns an integer, the nesting depth of s. You can assume that s is well-parenthesized: that is, that is, every "(" has a matching ")" after it and every ")" has a matching "(" before it.

Here are some examples to show how your function should work.

```
depth("22")
0
depth("(a+b)(a-b)")
1
depth("(a(b+c)-d)(e+f)")
2
```

this is what i tried

```
def depth(s):
    count,i=0,0;
    while i<=len(s):
        if s[i]=='(':
            count=count+1;
        if s[i]==')':
            return count
        i=i+1;
    return count

    #this is what i tried.
```

Comment: Don't just post your homework and expect us to do it for you.

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read - [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: definetly if i have a problem then i can share here. and i have tried but it is giving error. above is my code. @SrinivasSuresh

Comment: @AbhinandanSaraf You posted what you tried, but you need to also say what about it doesn't work, and exactly what you've already tried to fix it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate ok. actually i have no experience of asking questions on stack over flow. thanks, i will take care of that next time.

Comment: `def depth(s): return max(map(len, re.findall(r'\(*', re.sub(r'[^()]', '', s))))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def depth(s):
    count = 0
    max = 0
    for character in s:
        if character == "(":
            count += 1
            if count > max:
                max = count
        elif character == ")":
            count -= 1
    return max
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive one just for fun, if you want it:

```
def depth(str, index=0, counter=0, max_depth=0):

    while index < len(str):
        if str[index] == '(':
            counter += 1
            counter, index, max_depth = depth(str, index+1, counter, max_depth)
            counter = 0
            index += 1
            continue

        if str[index] == ')':
            if counter > max_depth:
                max_depth = counter

            return counter, index, max_depth

        else:
            index += 1

    return max_depth
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def depth(s):
count,i=0,0;
while i<=len(s):
    if s[i]=='(':
        count=count+1;
    if s[i]==')':
        return count
    i=i+1;
return count

#this is what i tried.
```

Comment: this will fail in any case where the max depth occures after the first closing